# Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting a "Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined" error in my react native app after doing some refactoring. I am unclear what's causing the issue, but appears to be related to how I am importing/exporting something into the file below.

My root `App()` code looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Navigator from './navigation/navigator';
import { LoginScreen } from './screens/LoginScreen';

export default function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsloggedIn] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsloggedIn(true);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
  return (
    isLoggedIn ? (
      <Navigator />
    ) : (
      <LoginScreen />
    )
  );
}
```

And the `navigator` file I am importing into the above file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Feather } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { LoginScreen } from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import { CaseloadScreen } from '../screens/CaseloadScreen';
import { PatientScreen } from '../screens/PatientScreen';
import { WeeklyScreen } from '../screens/WeeklyScreen';
import { ProfileScreen } from '../screens/ProfileScreen';

import { Ionicons, FontAwesome, MaterialCommunityIcons, AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { AvailablePatientScreen } from '../screens/AvailablePatientScreen';

const CustomDrawerContent = (props) => {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} style={{
        activeTintColor: {
          color: '#fff',
        },
      }} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigation = ({ navigation }) => {
  const icons = {
    tintColor: '#fff',
    size: 20,
  }
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName={'Caseload'}
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
      options={{
        headerLeft: (
          <View>
            <Feather name='menu' size={24} 
              onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} 
              color={'blue'} style={{}} />
          </View>
        ),
      }}
      screenOptions={{
        labelStyle: {
          color: '#fff',
        },
        inactiveTintColor: {
          color: '#fff',
        },
        drawerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(61,77,138)',
          width: 240,
          activeTintColor: 'rgb(61,77,138)',
          activeBackgroundColor: '#fff',
          inactiveTintColor: '#fff',
          inactiveBackgroundColor: 'rgb(61,77,138)',
        },
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Caseload" component={CaseloadScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (<Ionicons name="ios-home" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Weekly Summary" component={WeeklyScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (<FontAwesome name="bar-chart" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Available RiverKids" component={AvailablePatientScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (<FontAwesome name="child" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="My Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (<AntDesign name="profile" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="The Guys" component={TheGuysScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (<Ionicons name="ios-chatbubbles" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Patient" component={PatientScreen} options={{
          drawerItemStyle: { display: 'none' },
          headerShown: false,
      }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ title: 'Sign Out', 
        drawerIcon: () => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="logout" size={icons.size} color={icons.tintColor} />)
      }} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function Navigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigation />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The one other import in the root is for `LoginScreen`, which looks like this:

```
import {
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Keyboard,
  View,
  Image,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

import styles from '../styles';
import { GradientButton } from '../components/GradientButton';

export const LoginScreen = (props) => {
  console.log('props: ', props);
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}
    >
      <View style={styles.login.container}>
        // Other code
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
```